# ProcessBuilder for Mac OS & Linux

Tags: java, linux, macos, processbuilder

I'm trying to create a process builder that executes a .jar from cmd line. I have it working on windows just fine, but since I'm not familiar with how mac or linux works, I don't know their cmd line.

Here's my code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "java", "-jar", Settings.SAVE_DIR + Settings.SAVE_NAME});
            pb.directory(new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin"));
            final Process proc = pb.start();
```

Can anyone help me find the cmd line for linux/mac?

Comment: What is value of `Settings.SAVE_DIR` and `Settings.SAVE_NAME`?

Comment: @Andreas SAVE_NAME = "name.jar";
 SAVE_DIR = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator;

Comment: Is jar file actually at `~/name.jar`? In what way is your code not working?

Answer (score 1):

Err, why do you want to run a Java application from within Java using a process builder?

Just make sure that the other JAR is in your classpath; and then run the "main method" of that JAR. If you are worried about separation; you can still use a special classloader for that thing.

So, why the detour of fork'ing your JVM?

And regarding your actual question: simply try to build your command ... manually first. What I mean is: open a shell on a linux/mac system, and *type* the command line you have in mind; and keep trying until you get it working. Then look at that; and identify the easiest way to create that thing in a platform-independent manner.

Comment: Using reflection to execute the main method is buggy with the program I'm trying to execute. ClassLoader doesn't seem to load all the resources inside the program I'm executing, and overriding loadResource, is a lot more work then I need to do.